# Question about some grammar structures in the sentence

Tags: grammar, words, particles, phrases

While I was learing Japanese  through [小1くちばし音読・授業・クイズ2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpIC6GJHaTo), I came acorss sentences at at about the 7 minute mark (thanks to @Leebo) as this:

> 正解ですね、ここの部分なんですね、この羽がさ頭の部分からぴょんと違う方向に出ているでしょう。これのことを「冠羽」という風に言うんですね。冠のような羽という意味です。けれども、この羽があるものがオームになります。羽のないもの、似てるけれども小さくて羽のないものが、「インコ」という風になっています。たまにね、**インコなんだけどをオウムって名前がついたりもするそうなので**、見分けるときに気をつけてください。

The teacher is talking about the way to distinguish 「オウム」 and 「インコ」, and she says:

> インコなんだけどをオウムって名前がついたりもするそうなので、見分けるときに気をつけてください。

I don't quite understand the grammar of 「なんだけど」, 「を」, and 「そう」 here. Also, I don't quite understand the phrase 「名前がつく」.

My understanding:

- 「なんだけど」 measn "A, but B", as in 今日は休みなんだけど、朝早く起きた。(I'm off work today, but I got up early this morning.) But this rule doesn't work here, because what comes after 「なんだけど」 isn't another sentence, it's a particle 「を」, it's strange for me.
- 「を」 is mainly used to indicate the object, but the verb used here is 「名前がついたり」, which doesn't need any object.
- 「そう」 may be used as a 様態の助動詞 or 伝聞の助動詞, but it seems neither fits here.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: It helps to tell people where in the video they need to watch to find the part you're talking about, so they don't have to spend time scrolling through the whole thing. It's at about the 7 minute mark. I don't personally hear the を you're asking about, myself.

Comment: @Leebo Thanks for pointing out that, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: The subtitles say なんだけどを which seems to be a typo. she actually says なんだけども.

Comment: nice catch @broccolifacemask-cloth :) guess that clears up most of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Japanese

質問1と2について

「なんだけどを」はおかしいと思います。そのような言い方はしたことがありません。
もしそれが「なんだけども」ならば問題ないです。なので質問者さんに同意します。

質問3について

インコなんだけどもオウムって名前がついたりもするそうなので、見分けるときに気をつけてください。

だと仮定した場合、「そう」は伝聞を表すと思います。

---

## English

About question 1 & 2

I've never heard the phrase "なんだけどを". We don't say like that.
If it's "なんだけど" or "なんだけども", it makes sense.

About question 3

Assuming the phrase is

インコ**なんだけども**オウムって名前がついたりもするそうなので、見分けるときに気をつけてください。

, as you mentioned above, 「そう」 is 伝聞.

Comment: 「なんだけども」と「なんだけど」はどう違いますか？教えてください。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 違いはないです！私の感覚では「なんだけど」をよく使います。「なんだけども」はおじいちゃんやおばあちゃんが使う感覚です。あくまで個人の感想です。

No difference!! I and people around me say "なんだけど" but don`t say "なんだけども". It's my opinion that elderly people tend to say "なんだけども" more often.

Answer (score 3):

> オウムって名前がついたりも**するそうな**ので

> 「そう」 may be used as a 様態の助動詞 or 伝聞の助動詞

The そう should be 伝聞の助動詞. Compare:

> 「するそう(だ)」 -- 伝聞の助動詞
> 「しそう(だ)」 -- 様態の助動詞

伝聞の助動詞「そうだ」 is attached to the terminal form of a verb (動詞の終止形).
e.g. 「食べるそうだ」「言うそうだ」「降るそうだ」
様態の助動詞「そうだ」 is attached to the continuative form of a verb (動詞の連用形).
e.g. 「食べそうだ」「言いそうだ」「降りそうだ」

<sub>According to 明鏡国語辞典:

そうだ

 **様態** [...] 語法(1) **動詞**・助動詞「（ら）れる」「（さ）せる」**の連用形**、形容詞・形容動詞の語幹、助動詞「たい」「ない」の活用しない部分に付く。形容詞「ない」「よい」の場合は「異論はなさそうだ」「気分はよさそうだ」のように語幹と「そうだ」の間に「さ」が入る。助動詞「たい」「ない」の場合は、「た」「な」に付いて「何か言いたそうだ」「何も知らなそうだ」のようになる。「言いたさそうだ」「知らなさそうだ」などは標準的でない。

 **伝聞** [...] 語法(1) **活用語の終止形**に付く。と違い、「そうでない」や「そうだった」など、打ち消しの形や過去の形は用いられない。</sub>

---

インコなんだけどを should be a typo for インコなんだけども, as @broccoli has said in the comment.